# Autolayout: Can't lay out two views, one left aligned and the other right aligned

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm facing strange behaviour with autolayout. I want to add a container view to the viewcontroller and then add two labels: one is has its left aligned to the left of the container, while the other has its right aligned to the right of the container.
Left label is correctly layed out but right label no. I just discovered adding 20 points that right label is right aligned to parent's left edge and not to the right! Why? What am i doing wrong?

```
{
NSArray *cons = nil;
NSLayoutConstraint *cc = nil;

UIView *container = [[UIView alloc]init];
[container setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.view addSubview:container];

cons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-0-[view]-0-|"
                                               options: 0
                                               metrics:nil
                                                 views:@{@"view" : container}];

for (NSLayoutConstraint *con in  cons)
    [self.view addConstraint:con];

cons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[view]-0-|"
                                               options: 0
                                               metrics:nil
                                                 views:@{@"view" : container}];

for (NSLayoutConstraint *con in  cons)
    [self.view addConstraint:con];



UILabel *currentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[currentLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[currentLabel setText:@"Punti attuali"];
[currentLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[container addSubview:currentLabel];


cc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentLabel
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:container
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                 multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];

[container addConstraint:cc];


cc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentLabel
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:container
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];

[container addConstraint:cc];



UILabel *currentPoint = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[currentPoint setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[currentPoint setText:@"100"];
[currentPoint setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[container addSubview:currentPoint];

cc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentPoint
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:container
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                 multiplier:0.f constant:20.f];


[container addConstraint:cc];

cc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:currentPoint
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:container
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];

[container addConstraint:cc];
```

}

This should be a very eary task to accomplish but i'm spending hour and can't find a solution.

Comment: Why is your multiplier `0` on the right-alignment constraint?

Comment: Also: there's a method called `addConstraints` that will let you add an array of constraints so you don't need to loop through the array and add them individually.

Comment: Also, no need to use zeros to make a 0 length constraint. This @"|[view]|" is equivalent to  @"|-0-[view]-0-|"

Comment: Can't vote your comments, but obviously you were right! I'm sorry, i came to this easy task trying to solve a bigger one (scrollview with dynamic sizes) and i must have messed with constraints, setting multiplier to 0, so thanks a lot, i wouldn't have seen it with my tired eyes! The for loop came from tutorial code...